# Azure Managed Cache without webconfig

Tags: c#, azure, caching

I am using the Azure Redis Cache following the tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-service/ . How I can use this cache **without** using the webconfig? Here is my code.

The c# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MoviesDB.CacheWrappers
{

    public class AzureManagedCache 
    {


        DataCache AzureCache = new DataCache("default");
        public void Add(string sqlQuery, DataTable records)
        {
            List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();
            movies = MovieDBContext.ConvertToMovies(records);
            AzureCache.Add("sqlQuery", movies);
        }

        public void Delete(string sqlQuery)
        {
            AzureCache.Remove("sqlQuery");
        }

        public object Read(string sqlQuery)
        {
            var movie = AzureCache.Get("sqlQuery");
            return movie;
        }



    }
}
```

and the webconfig.xml

```
<dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default">
      <!--To use the in-role flavor of Windows Azure Cache, set identifier to be the cache cluster role name 
      To use the Windows Azure Cache Service, set identifier to be the endpoint of the cache cluster--> 
      <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="******.cache.windows.net" />

      <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />

      <!--Use this section to specify security settings for connecting to your cache. This section is not required if your cache is hosted on a role that is a part of your cloud service.--> 
      <securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="true">
        <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="******" />
      </securityProperties>
    </dataCacheClient>
  </dataCacheClients>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code to programmatically talk to managed cache:

```
var cacheSvcUri = "<your-cache-name>.cache.windows.net";

// Setup DataCacheSecurity configuration
string cacheSvcAcsKey = "<your-acs-key>";
var secureAcsKey = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in cacheSvcAcsKey)
{
secureAcsKey.AppendChar(c);
}
secureAcsKey.MakeReadOnly();

// Setup the DataCacheFactory configuration
DataCacheFactoryConfiguration dcfConfig = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();

// Set autodiscover for in-role

dcfConfig.AutoDiscoverProperty = new DataCacheAutoDiscoverProperty(true, cacheSvcUri);

DataCacheSecurity factorySecurity = new DataCacheSecurity(secureAcsKey);
dcfConfig.SecurityProperties = factorySecurity;

// Create a configured DataCacheFactory object.
DataCacheFactory dcf= new DataCacheFactory(dcfConfig); // make the DataCacheFactory static as it connects to the cache cluster.

// Get a cache client for the default cache.
DataCache defaultCache = dcf.GetDefaultCache();

defaultCache.Put("One", 1);
defaultCache.Put("Two", 2);
```

You can add your cache operations after defining which named cache to talk to within the cache tenant. Here, it is "default" (`DataCache defaultCache = dcf.GetDefaultCache()`). If you want to talk to any other named cache, then it would have been `DataCache defaultCache = dcf.GetCache("<your-named-cache>")`